# Display only the n'th match of grep

Tags: bash, grep, pattern-matching, match

```
onefish
onechicken
twofish
twochicken
twocows
threechicken
```

What if I want to grep for lines containing "two", but I only want the 2nd match. So I want the result "twochicken".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try this:

```
awk '/two/{i++}i==2' file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "onefish
onechicken
twofish
twochicken
twocows
threechicken"|awk '/two/{i++}i==2'
twochicken
```

**note**: if your file is huge, do this:

```
awk '/two/{i++}i==2{print; exit}' file
```

Comment: the second option is superior regardless of filesize, no ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'line number' ? i meant that adding `{print; exit}` would be good idea for any input size... oh. that was option #3 actually ;) i counted wrong)))

Comment: is there a way to stop at nth occurrence of the word? I mean, if the "word" is repeated multiple times in a single line?

Comment: @anishsane i think there is.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a the `search-pattern` and the no. of occurence `N` as a string

Comment: @WanderingMind yes, you can define variables

Comment: Can you edit your answer to let me know how to pass a variable as search pattern

Comment: `awk -v p="two" -v n="2" '$0~p{i++}i==n' file` @WanderingMind

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: This is buggy -- if you remove `twocows` from the example, then it prints *both* `twocows` and `threechickens`, because `i` only iterates on lines that include "two" -- so if `i` reaches 2 on the last occurrence of the target string, then `i` remains 2 throughout the rest of the file, and every subsequent line is printed. (However, the "if your file is huge" addendum fixes this bug.)

Comment: @Kent can you please explain what does `{i++}i==2` do?

Comment: @ManuelJordan `/two/{A} i==2 {B}` = `if($0~/two) do A; if(i==2) do B`

Answer (score 46):

```
grep -m2 "two" in-file.txt | tail -n1
```

Stop after the second match, then take the second line printed.

Comment: that does not exactly do what is expected. if there are more matches than two, it will output multiple lines...

Comment: The tail should be: `tail -n1`.

Comment: @poncha: really?  The grep -m2 makes sure there are only two matches.  I changed it anyway, though I think it was OK before.

Comment: This is a really poor answer, because it doesn't work for multi-line matches (i.e. in combination with `-A` or  `-B`. HOWEVER, none of the other alternatives works for multi-line matches either.

Comment: A possible solution for multi-line results is described under https://superuser.com/questions/1086675/using-grep-how-do-i-show-the-nth-occurence-of-a-pattern.

Answer (score 9):

grep and sed can be used to filter the line number.

**testfile**:

```
onefish
onechicken
twofish
twochicken
threechicken
twocows
```

**Getting the desired line:**

```
grep "two" testfile | sed -n 2p
prints "twochicken"

grep "two" testfile | sed -n 1p
prints "twofish"
```

Answer (score 5):

To use `grep` command for the n_th match, we can use the combination of `head` and `tail` commands like this:

```
grep two file.txt | head -n1 | tail -1
```

where `n1` is the n_th match we need.

Answer (score 1):

If the word (here word==two) repeats multiple time in a single line, & you want to print that line, use below:

```
word=two
n=2
line=`grep -m$n $word -o -n MyFile | sed -n $n's/:.*//p'`
awk 'FNR=='$line'{print; exit}' MyFile
```

e.g.
For below input:

```
onefish
onechicken
twotwofish
twochicken
twocows
threechicken
```

it will print `twotwofish`, instead of `twochicken`.

This may not be what user1787038 wants, but added to answer my own comment.

Comment: `-m$n` in grep line is just for some optimization, not needed for functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that if the `threechicken` and `twocows` lines were swapped, aka:

```
onefish
onechicken
twofish
twochicken
threechicken
twocows
```

then Kent's first response (`awk '/two/{i++}i==2' file`) would yield the output:

```
twochicken
threechicken
```

because it takes another occurrence of the match to increment the counter. His last response: `awk '/two/{i++}i==2{print; exit}' file` avoids this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about grep so let's stick with it:

```
$ cat testfile
onefish
onechicken
twofish
twochicken
twocows
threechicken

$ grep two testfile | while read line; do
    ((n++))
    ((n==2)) && { echo "$line"; break; }
done
twochicken
```