# How do I go to the Xth match in vim?

Tags: linux, vim, command-line

I want to find the 2892216th match using a regular expression in vim (technically any linux tool that could give the context to the 2892216th match would suffice)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135430/display-only-the-nth-match-of-grep) answer has some nice ways to do it with `awk`.  Since your file is so large it may be more efficient than using vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say `2892216/regex` in vim.  Make sure that you are at the beginning of file or the count will be wrong.  It is nth match from the current position.

Comment: Note: that if the cursor starts on a match this will be off by one.