# print only the n-th match using awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

This one is asked many times and still I am unable to solve.
A part of my file looks like:

```
 GKKRBSF:: ewrat=   0.00000 (<1 searchk, >1 searche)
           dirat=   0.00000 (Direct Summation ratio)
nhat,betah=  0.1000D+01 0.0000D+00 0.1000D+01      0.10000D+00
nhat,betah=  0.1000D+01 0.0000D+00 0.1000D+01      0.10000D+00
nhat,betah=  0.1000D+01 0.0000D+00 0.1000D+01      0.10000D+01
nhat,betah=  0.1000D+01 0.0000D+00 0.1000D+01      0.10000D+01
nhat,betah=  0.1000D+01 0.0000D+00 0.1000D+01      0.10000D+00
```

This is somewhere in between the file. I have to get $5 of first and n-th(say,3rd in this particular example) match of `nhat,betah`.
For the first line, I can easily do a:

```
var_M=`awk '/nhat,betah=/{print  $5;exit}' filename`
```

But, how can I get the 3rd line and exit?
I tried, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135430/display-only-the-nth-match-of-grep) thread, as:

```
var_M=`awk '/nhat,betah=/{j++}j=3{print  $5;exit}' filename`
```

And this is giving the 5th column of the 3rd line of the file, without matching the pattern.
Surely I am missing something.
Any help please?

Comment: You should avoid using the old back-tics and use parentheses. `var_M=$(code)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep track of how many times it appeared:

```
$ awk '/nhat,betah=/{i++; if (i==3) {print $5; exit}}' file
0.30000D+01
```

#### Explanation

You almost had it, it was just a matter of putting the condition inside in a proper way:

From

```
var_M=$(awk '/nhat,betah=/{j++} j=3{print  $5;exit}' filename)
                                 ^
```

to

```
var_M=$(awk '/nhat,betah=/{j++} j==3{print  $5;exit}' filename)
                                 ^^
```

---

Note I changed the last column to `0.NumberOfLine` to make it more clear which line it is outputting:

```
 GKKRBSF:: ewrat=   0.00000 (<1 searchk, >1 searche)
           dirat=   0.00000 (Direct Summation ratio)
nhat,betah=  0.1000D+01 0.0000D+00 0.1000D+01      0.10000D+00
nhat,betah=  0.1000D+01 0.0000D+00 0.1000D+01      0.20000D+00
nhat,betah=  0.1000D+01 0.0000D+00 0.1000D+01      0.30000D+01
nhat,betah=  0.1000D+01 0.0000D+00 0.1000D+01      0.40000D+01
nhat,betah=  0.1000D+01 0.0000D+00 0.1000D+01      0.50000D+00
```

Comment: can be shorter :-)  `awk '/nhat,betah=/&&(++i==3){print $5; exit}' file`